# Understanding lexical scoping in golang

Tags: go, lexical-scope

https://play.golang.org/p/kK9c71Yt9N - This is the code I'm working off of.

I'm trying to understand lexical scoping for the variable `X`. If I use the `:=` operator in line 11, `X` defined outside of `func main` gets hidden and a new scope is getting created within the function. If I use the `=` operator in the same line, the compiler complains that `err` is undefined.

My understanding is that the `:=` operator creates variables which are not defined and hence, only `err` has to get defined. But, this understanding is clearly wrong.

What code changes can I do to make sure `X` is not redefined within `main()`?

I know I can do the following to make sure `X` is not redefined within `main()`:

```
var err error
X, err = InitX()
```

Is there a better way that I might be missing?

Comment: You are not redefine nothing. In your code inside the main you are declaring err and then assign two values foreach variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that the := operator creates variables which are
>   not defined and hence, only err has to get defined.

This is expected and your workaround is OK. It is described in some detail in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html).

> In a `:=` declaration a variable v may appear even if it has already
>   been declared, provided:
>
> - this declaration is in the same scope as the existing declaration of v
>     (**if v is already declared in an outer scope, the declaration will
>     create a new variable** §),
> - the corresponding value in the
>     initialization is assignable to v, and
> - there is at least one other
>     variable in the declaration that is being declared anew.